# Python - Incremental loop doesn't increment properly

Tags: python

I am using an API that returns me articles in my language in determined categories. This API limits me in 100 calls for each interval of `60 minutes`.

I'm trying to download a 100 articles within this `100 calls/hour` window.

The way I chose to do that (to avoid downloading  100 files straight away) would be to randomly choose 100 numbers between 0 and 60*60. These are the seconds on which I make requests. Sort them and as my function progress through the array, each time it waits for `next - current` seconds.

For that, I made a function that generates 100 unique numbers between 0 and 3600 `(3600 seconds = 1 hour)` and sorts them:

```
def generateTimes():
    download_wait_times = random.sample(xrange(3600), 100) #Generates 100 unique numbers between 0 and 3600( 3600 seconds = 1 hour).
    download_wait_times.sort() #Sorts the numbers.
    return download_wait_times
```

Contents of download_wait_times:

```
>>> print like_times
[15, 43, 51, 85, 98, 130, 157, 159, 181, 233, 336, 371, 390, 456, 458, 481, 488, 503, 539, 594, 637, 650, 698, 795, 837, 851, 963, 1001, 1020, 1027, 1045, 1081, 1163, 1187, 1191, 1239, 1316, 1405, 1585, 1625, 1657, 1658, 1753, 1807, 1881, 1902, 1933, 1941, 2001, 2022, 2050, 2132, 2167, 2169, 2220, 2252, 2314, 2386, 2391, 2392, 2485, 2500, 2505, 2558, 2584, 2651, 2656, 2657, 2662, 2721, 2730, 2790, 2796, 2872, 2902, 2913, 2935, 2941, 2951, 2974, 3045, 3047, 3066, 3128, 3163, 3211, 3218, 3316, 3354, 3361, 3397, 3424, 3428, 3436, 3492, 3498, 3534, 3541, 3544, 3552]
```

Then, this function loops though my list of articles, downloads one article and sleeps following my formula, `next` wait time `minus` `current` wait time:

```
def myFunction():
    for media in download_list[0]:
        api.download_file(media) #Downloads the article
        downloaded += 1 
        print("Downloaded file: %s. " % media + "Total number of files downloaded: %d. " % downloaded)

        print "Sleeping for %d seconds." % download_wait_times[time_count]
        time_count =+ 1
        time.sleep(download_wait_times[time_count+1] - download_wait_times[time_count]) #next minus current
```

When I run my script, this is the output:

```
>>> execfile('test.py')
downloaded 905462027415412779. Number of downloaded articles: 1. 
Sleeping for 15 seconds.
downloaded 905462008013920125. Number of downloaded articles: 2. 
Sleeping for 43 seconds.
downloaded 905445715499119709. Number of downloaded articles: 3. 
Sleeping for 43 seconds.
downloaded 905461942110434199. Number of downloaded articles: 4. 
Sleeping for 43 seconds.
downloaded 905461981722457386. Number of downloaded articles: 5. 
Sleeping for 43 seconds.
downloaded 905461979140234589. Number of downloaded photos: 6. 
Sleeping for 43 seconds.
```

Instead of sleeping for the next amount of time, which would be `51`, it gets stucked sleeping for `43` seconds, and I can't figure out why.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `time_count =+ 1` should be `time_count += 1`.

Comment: What is the difference between `=+` and `+=`?

Comment: The first one is if you were just doing `a = +1`, like `a = -1`. You wouldn't expect that to do anything else but the normal kind of assignment. `a +=` or `a -=` increments from the `a`'s previous value.

Comment: Can the downvotters please explain why you are downvotting? It was an honest question, and it was neither egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, as the section `When should I vote down` here http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down advices.

Comment: @viniciusmunich I agree with you, it's an honest question. Easy to mix up when you're starting out. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
time_count =+ 1
```

This must be;

```
time_count += 1
```

First one is equal to `time_count = 1`. Second is `time_count = time_count + 1`.

On the first one actually you are saying `variable time_count equals to positive one (+1)`. This is the difference between them. You can remember that like this;

For example you want to decrease a variable, if you write this;

```
x = -1
```

Easily you can see it's re-define the variable. So you remember that you have to write it like;

```
x -= 1
```

So you have to do that when you increase a variable, if you write this;

```
x = +1
```

As you see on the first example it's re-defining it. Valid one is;

```
x += 1
```

Comment: What is the difference?